# Why Wont NSIndexPath Work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I was mading a simple demo with `UITableView`:When one cell is selected , show a tick in the cell and the last selected cell would be unticked , when run in simulator,it is good when select one cell for the first time,While if selected another cell,The application would be crushed without any log info, I didn't know what happened. Here is what i did in coding :

**Header:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSIndexPath * oldIndexPath;
    NSArray *list;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *list;
@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(oldIndexPath == nil){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }else{
        UITableViewCell * oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    oldIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Any help is appreciated,Thanks

Comment: in your coding you are Making Unchecked for the checked cell But you are not making Check mark for new cell. Check my answer and let me know.

Comment: Yeah,I found out the logic is wrong,Thanks

Comment: This is the finally version that could work perfect.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    if(oldIndexPath != nil){
        UITableViewCell * oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        
    }
    self.oldIndexPath = indexPath;
}

Comment: Tap the same Row (Selected) two times, it Won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always access your properties via `self.`, don't access the ivar directly. By directly assigning you are bypassing any memory management used in the accessor methods, and when you later use the value, it has been released.

In the current version of Xcode, you don't need to declare ivars to back properties or use synthesize. This prevents you accidentally directly accessing the ivars.

Comment: Yes,You are right,I should use self.oldIndexPath but not access oldIndexPath direct.Otherwise will lead to ACCESS BAD ADDRESS issue as oldIndexPath has been released .Always forget this since have worked with java for several years.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Hope it will Work for you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


{

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if(self.oldIndexPath != nil)

{

    UITableViewCell * oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.oldIndexPath];
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



self.oldIndexPath = indexPath;
```

}

Comment: EVen though the LOGIC is not correct in coding,But the actual reason is i didn't use self.oldIndexPath = indexPath,Such that the oldIndexPath variable is not actually "retained" and lead to ACCESS BAD ADDRESS issue.